# Normalize integer values in multi-byte php strings

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, internationalization, multibyte

Lets say I have the UTF-8 string `0123456789०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯`.  I would like to replace all the non-ASCII integer values with their ASCII equivalent so the provided string would become `012345678901234567890123456789`.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: [mb_convert_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding)? utf-8 -> ascii?

Answer (score 3):

If your PHP has php_intl extension, you may use Transliterate class.

```
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '<')) {
    exit ('Transliterator is available on PHP 5.4.0 or later.');
}    
if (!class_exists('Transliterator')) {
    exit ('You need to install php_intl extension.');
}
$any2latin = Transliterator::create("Any-Latin");

$original = "0123456789०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯";
echo $any2latin->transliterate($original), "\n";
```

I got this,

```
012345678901234567890123456789
```

For case when you need to normalize specific language, I left my initial code below.

```
$devanagari2latin = Transliterator::create("Devanagari-Latin");
$bengali2latin = Transliterator::create("Bengali-Latin");

$original = "0123456789०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯";
echo $bengali2latin->transliterate($devanagari2latin->transliterate($original)), "\n";
```

Comment: In this specific case we only had Devnagari and Bengali. What if we throw in some Tibetan in the mix? Or want to implement a general solution?

Comment: Thank you @Shervin. I misunderstood the requirement so fixed the sample.

Comment: I new there had to be a library that handled this.  Now I know what Transliteration is.  To bad it's not available in 5.3

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert numbers from different languages into standard Arabic representation? I don't think, that such function exists in standard PHP. So, you'll have to write it yourself. Fortunately, it's not hard to do. Just create hashes of non-standard digits and convert them all to standard. For example this script replaces Chinese numbers to Arabic:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    '零' => 0,
    '壹' => 1,
    '貳' => 2,
    '參' => 3,
    '肆' => 4,
    '伍' => 5,
    '陸' => 6,
    '柒' => 7,
    '捌' => 8,
    '玖' => 9,
    );

$str = '零壹貳參肆伍陸柒捌玖';
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
    $str = str_replace($key, $value, $str);
}

print $str;
```

Prints:

```
0123456789
```

Comment: Thanks, this works and is very simple if you are only worried about one or two languages.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix my original approach which, I think, is better than maintaining a huge array of conversions.

```
function NormalizeDigit($val) {
    $zeros = array (
        0x0660,    // Arabic-Indic
        0x06F0,    // Extended Arabic-Indic
        0x07C0,    // NKO
        0x0966,    // Devanagari
        0x09E6,    // Bengali
        0x0A66,    // Gurmukhi
        0x0AE6,    // Gujarati
        0x0B66,    // Oriya
        0x0BE6,    // Tamil
        0x0C66,    // Telugu
        0x0CE6,    // Kannada
        0x0D66,    // Malayalam
        0x0E50,    // Thai
        0x0ED0,    // Lao
        0x0F20,    // Tibetan
        0x1040,    // Myanmar
        0x1090,    // Myanmar Shan
        0x17E0,    // Khmer
        0x1810,    // Mongolian
        0x1946,    // limbu
        0x19D0,    // NEW TAI LUE
        0x1B50,    // BALINESE
        0x1BB0,    // SUNDANESE
        0x1C40,    // LEPCHA
        0x1C50,    // OL CHIKI
        0xA620,    // VAI
        0xA8D0,    // SAURASHTRA
        0xA900,    // KAYAH LI
        0xAA50,    // CHAM
        0xFF10);   // Full Width Japanese

    foreach ($zeros as $zero) {
        if (($val >= $zero) && ($val <= $zero + 9)) {
            return 0x30 + ($val - $zero);
        }
    }
    return $val;
}

function NormalizeDigits($str) {
    $wide = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16', $str);
    for($i = 2; $i < strlen($wide); $i += 2) {
        $wc = (ord($wide[$i]) << 8) | ord($wide[$i + 1]);
        $wc = NormalizeDigit($wc);
        $wide[$i] = chr($wc >> 8);
        $wide[$i + 1] = chr($wc);
    }
    return iconv('UTF-16', 'UTF-8', $wide);
}
```